# What are the best models/methods for training when the target is multidimensional?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, train

I am not very familiar with all methods in Machine Learning. However, I know for example when I apply linear regression, the y is always assumed to be one-dimensional.

My target is multi-dimensional. One approach would be to train a model for each dimension. But I wonder if there are other approaches that considers all dimensions together (so not to consider them independently, like if I train a different linear regression model for each dimension)?

Answer (score 0):

We usually "reduce" multidimensional target to a single number. For example using [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy).

Here is an example of calculation in python. (from [this link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cross-entropy-for-machine-learning/))

```
# example of calculating cross entropy
from math import log2

# calculate cross entropy
def cross_entropy(p, q):
    return -sum([p[i]*log2(q[i]) for i in range(len(p))])

# define data
p = [0.10, 0.40, 0.50]
q = [0.80, 0.15, 0.05]

# calculate cross entropy H(P, Q)
ce_pq = cross_entropy(p, q)
print('H(P, Q): %.3f bits' % ce_pq)
```

Think about this is for one data point, the output of the model $\hat y$ is vector $p$ and the target is vector $q$. The above calculation will get the loss in one dimension.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be an interesting method. But I guess in my problem I need to consider all dimensions and my prediction should be also consisted of similar amount of dimensions.